# Swift Framework - How import sqlite3.h to umbrella file

Tags: ios, swift, sqlite, frameworks

I'm trying to do a swift framework to reuse some of the code of my swift previous project, this framework used some Objective-C classes (this classes are added to the umbrella file) and others swift classes that use classes from static libraries (that's the problem).

I try to add to the framework the static library "libsqlite3.0.tbd" and use the "sqlite3.h" class inside a swift class but I'm not sure the way to do that. 
I tried to add "sqlite3.h" to the umbrella file 
`#import <sqlite3.h>`

but y recibe this error

> Include of non-modular header inside framework module 'Ulan'

In my project this class was added to the bridge header file, but now, in the framework I am not how use it.

Thanks for your help